# Submission handler for the user registration form doesn't work

Tags: 7, forms

I'm working on a Drupal 7 portal. I added a custom field to the registration form and I would like to get hold of custom field value when the registration form is submitted and before it is stored in the database.

I'm trying to use the submission handler for the registration form and print the content of `$form` and `$form_state`, but those values never get printed as message. I installed the Devel module as well.

```
function user_register_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($form, 1) .'</pre>');
    drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($form_state, 1) .'</pre>'); 
    drupal_set_message(t('An info message from user_register_form_submit'), 'error');
}
```

I appreciate any input on what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

In `hook_form_alter` use foloowing code

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'user_register_form'){
    $form['#submit'][] = 'module_custom_form_submit';
   }
}
```

after that use

```
function module_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    // Do whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: The question is _Why isn't the content of `$form` and `$form_state` printed?_

Comment: Are you talking about my solution?

Comment: I am commenting on your answer. The OP is asking a different question. (_I'm trying to use the submission handler for the registration form and print the content of `$form` and `$form_state`, **but those values never get printed as message**. I installed the Devel module as well. I appreciate any input on what the issue could be._)

Comment: The reason nothing is printed might be `user_register_form_submit` is not properly registered as a submission handler. Hence Jeetendra Kumar's answer.

Comment: @KirillShabunov This answer doesn't make clear the reason of the suggestion. If the OP doesn't understand what he is doing wrong, this answer doesn't explain what is wrong in the OP's code.

Comment: This code is working for me. I am using the same code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in the shown code.

1. Simply defining a function is not sufficient for Drupal to consider it a form submission handler, not even if the function name ends with `_form_submit`. To add a new form submission handler, the module you are developing needs to implement [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) or [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x), and add a new form submission handler.

   ```
   function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
     $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_submit';
   }
   ```
2. To debug a form submission handler you should use [`watchdog()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7.x). Once the *Database logging* module is installed, on admin/reports/dblog you can read all the messages added with `watchdog()`.